# ASK linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, diagonalization, nonlinear-system

#### Concept of linear independent

#### A. The linear system Ax=b has unique solution for b, then the columns of A are linearly independent
B. The column of the change-of-coordinate matrix P are linearly independent

C. The subset of a linearly-dependent vector set is linearly-dependent

D. If A is diagonalization, then A has linearly-independent columns

E. If AT*A(AT means transpose of A) is invertible, then A has linearly-independent columns

#### My answer is (A)(B)(E)

(A) A is invertible, so it is true

(B) true

(C) S={(1,0),(2,0)} and subset of S={(1,0)},so it is wrong

(D) A is diagonalization, does not mean A is invertible, so it is wrong

(E) determine of AT*A is not zero, so determine of A is not zero too

#### Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (A), it depends on what the author means by "$Ax=b$ has unique solution (for $b$?)", but the point is that when $A$ is $m\times n$ with $m>n$, we may select $b\notin \operatorname{col}A$, in which case $[\forall x,\forall y,((Ax=b\land Ay=b)\rightarrow x=y)]$ is true and $[\exists z, Az=b]$ is false.

The rest seems fine.

Comment: Okay! you mean if the question is "Ax=b  has unique solution for x": correct ,and "Ax=b  has unique solution for b": wrong?

Comment: I think that "for $b$" is just a mistake and that it should be "for $x$". The subsequent discussion applies to the assumption that there should be $x$. Anyways, the doubt on the interprtation of "$Ax=b$ has unique solution for $x$" stands, which is why I split my considerations up.

Comment: haha!! thanks for your response!